# don't show my Botton Bar in TableViewController

Tags: swift, swift3, bottombar

I'm tying to place a bar at the bottom of my table controller, but it does not work well for me.

I do this with Main.storyboard:
[image]

But don't show nothing. I tried different parameters: Opaque ToolBar, Translucent Toolbar...

Some advice?

Comment: Instead enabling 'Under Top Bars' and 'Under Bottom Bars' in storyboard, add tool bar manually at bottom of the screen.

Comment: I uncheck that options, but nothing ocurr :(

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add that to footer of tableview?

Comment: Yes, sure. Don't work for me. In the end, I solved it by creating an intermediate layer with a view. And on that view, I placed the rest of the elements: the tableview, the topbar and the bottom bar. That solved my problem. Thanks